# Facebook-Connect users changing email addresses on Facebook?

Tags: authentication, facebook

We're implementing a Facebook-connect mechanism to allow users to sign up into our system. We receive their email address and other details at sign up.

I'm not sure how to handle the scenario when the FB-user changes his email address at Facebook itself and subsequently logs into our system. I dont think there is a mechanism for us to detect that (or for facebook to notify us).

How do I resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table in your database that holds the FB userId, and the email address and use the FB id as a foreign key anywhere where you need to refer to that user. Then, at some regular event like when the user logs in, places an order, or updates their profile, etc., get the email from the facebook profile and update the table.